# Dynamic height of UITableViewCell and UIImageView inside

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

I have custom UITableViewCell like this:

[image]

Inside `UITableViewCell` I have `UICollectionView`, aligned at top with constraints, below it self-made Stepper (view with two Buttons and Label inside), aligned at right by constraints and with fixed width. From the left of `UITableViewCell` and to the leading of stepper there is an UIImageView, aligned by constraints and also with Aspect constraint (1:1 in preview, i.e. height = width). Stepper's bottom constrained to `UIImageView` bottom, and also at the bottom of `UIImageView` another view with Segmented Control and two Labels (named Material). Bottom of `UITableViewCell` constrained to Material's bottom.

I want to change `UIImageView` height by changing `UIImageView` Aspect constraint programmatically (by selecting item in `UICollectionView` at top) and so height of UITableViewCell, as well as the other bindings, are also changed. For example I want to set Aspect constraint to 2:3 or 4:5, 5:7.
I created `IBOutlet` for my Aspect constraint inside `UITableViewCell` class, and try to change it constant in `collectionView shouldSelectItemAt` method but nothing changes.
What am I doing wrong? I'm new to iOS development, please help me to figure out this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are changing aspects, just make multiple views in IB as it’s not only programming but also arts.

Comment: Do you mean to create multiple UIImageViews with own Aspect constraint and show only one of them on selecting UICollectionView appropriate item?

Comment: Yes . Also you can setting up a bunch of views to pick from